# Fire Up jQuery function more than once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure for a menu in my website

```
<div class="header">
        <ul>
            <li id="menu__lnk_one"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and I have linked the jquery and written the following code to add a class to menu__link_one item

```
$("#menu__lnk_one").hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass("animated shake");
        });
```

But the hover funcrion is called only once. How to make it working all the time more than once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you do not ever remove the "animated shake" class from your list item.  I am going under the assumption that your animated shake class has a one time animation that shakes it.  So once you have added the class to your item, it never can add it again since it already has it.  To solve this, you would need to remove it at some time, most likely whenever your mouse stops hovering over it.

Instead of using hover(), try using on() with "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events:

```
$("#menu__lnk_one").on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).addClass("animated shake");
});

$("#menu__lnk_one").on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).removeClass("animated shake");
});
```

Alternatively, you could try quickly removing the class right before you add it again, although I'm not 100% this will work, you may need a timeout delay between the two.

```
$("#menu__lnk_one").hover(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("animated shake").addClass("animated shake");
});
```

Doing it the latter way would leave your item with the shake class almost permanently after it has been hovered over once, which may not be the best way.